# How to handle Crtl+Click event in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I want to handle crtl+click event in WPF XAML code behind. I registered KeyDown event and MouseDown event, but I am not able to register for them together. What is that I am missing.

```
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key.Equals(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 1)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Usually you wouldn't bother with the KeyDown event and just check `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)` inside the mouse click handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother tracking Key Up/Down events--they're not reliable (e.g., user may switch windows between pressing and releasing).  Just check `Keyboard.Modifiers` when you process the click.

If you **only** want to handle `Ctrl+Click` and not, for example, `Ctrl+Shift+Click`, then check `Modifiers` for an exact match:

```
if (e.ClickCount == 1 && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) {
}
```

Otherwise, do a selective bitwise match:

```
if (e.ClickCount == 1 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0) {
}
```

`Keyboard.Modifiers` should generally be consistent: it won't reflect the release of the control key until *after* you process the mouse event, because all input events are processed in FIFO order.

Be sure to read up on bubbling versus tunneling events (e.g., `MouseDown` vs. `PreviewMouseDown`), and how events stop routing once they are marked as `Handled`.

---

As an alternative, you may be able to use a simple `MouseGesture` with a `MouseAction` of `LeftClick` and `Modifiers` of `Control`.  It really depends on what your UI looks like, and whether you want a chance at handling the event before any descendant controls.  Using a mouse gesture should work in (mostly) the same scenarios as handling the bubbling `MouseDown` event.  But if you need to rely on tunneling events like `PreviewMouseDown`, then a gesture wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah yes. This better than the suggestion in my comment because you don't need to account for left/right modifiers too.

Comment: Wow this works like a charm! Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this, with a flag:

```
bool _isControlPressed = false;

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        _isControlPressed = true;
    }
}

private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        _isControlPressed = false;
    }
}

private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 1 && _isControlPressed)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The `_isControlPressed` flag is set/unset in the key down/key up events. You can then use this flag in other methods to determine the key state.

Comment: This is only for LeftCtrl, would want it to work for any Ctrl press

Comment: @BlakeThingstad True, although I assumed because the OP only had `LeftCtrl` in the original post, that they only cared about that one key. It would be easy to extend for the right control.

Comment: That's fair, just want to make sure OP realizes this.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, because it is trivially to get into an inconsistent state.  All the user has to do is switch windows between pressing and releasing the control key.  Even if focus changes within the window, you may miss one event or the other, or even both.